# Pass variable to a class which extends another one

Tags: php

I'm using tFPDF class.

I'm extending this class using this code to get custom Header and Footer

```
class PDF extends tFPDF{
    function Header(){
        $this->Image('../../images/logo-admin.png',10,6,30);

        $this->SetFont('DejaVu','',13);
        $this->Cell(247,10,$produto,0,0,'C',false);

        $this->SetDrawColor(0,153,204);
        $this->SetFillColor(98,197,230);
        $this->SetTextColor(255);
        $this->Cell(30,10,date('d/m/Y'),1,0,'C',true);

        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    function Footer(){
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'P'.chr(225).'gina '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}
```

What I need to do, is to somehow change the `$produto` with a variable that doesn't belong to the class.

I'm calling this class using `$pdf = new PDF();`.

How may I pass a variable to this class so I can use a string, something like `$pdf = new PDF('SomeString');` and use it inside the class like `$this->somestring = $somestringfromoutside`

Comment: What's wrong with a constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `protected` var and declare a setter.

```
class PDF extends tFPDF {

protected $_produto = NULL;

public function Header(){
    /* .. */
    $this->Cell(247,10,$this->_getProduto(),0,0,'C',false);
    /* .. */
}

public function Footer(){
    /* .. */
}

public function setProduto($produto) {
    $this->_produto = $produto;
}

protected function _getProduto() {
    return $this->_produto;
}

}

// Using example 
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->setProduto('Your Value');
$pdf->Header();
```

Comment: This does what I need, thanks for your answer, I can't believe I didn't thought of the getter/setter method... Thanks! :)

Comment: Thx you too. However if you need a real getter you have to to refactor and expose the method `_getProudto()` changing `protected` in `public`. You could also remove the `_` prefix in the name, it's just a Zend Naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the __construct() method with a default parameter for $myString

```
class PDF extends tFPDF{
    public $somestring;

    function __construct($myString = '') {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->somestring = $myString;
    }

    function Header(){
        $this->Image('../../images/logo-admin.png',10,6,30);

        $this->SetFont('DejaVu','',13);
        $this->Cell(247,10,$produto,0,0,'C',false);

        $this->SetDrawColor(0,153,204);
        $this->SetFillColor(98,197,230);
        $this->SetTextColor(255);
        $this->Cell(30,10,date('d/m/Y'),1,0,'C',true);

        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    function Footer(){
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'P'.chr(225).'gina '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically only trying to inject the $producto variable.  It would be easy enough to make one change in your code like this:

```
function Header($producto){
```

This will allow you to pass a parameter to the Header function call.

Like this:

```
$tfpdf = new tFPDF();
$tfpdf->Header($producto);
```

If you really want to pass the value at the time of instantiation, then you need to define a constructor function, and probably a class property to store your $producto value.  You would then pass the $producto value into the contructor and set the property accordingly.  Then in your header function you would reference $this->producto instead of $producto.